# evento de mouse en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un panel y dentro del panel tengo 12 botones, lo cuales están invisibles, quiero que cuando en mouse entre con al panel mouseEntered  se me amplie un poco y muestre los botones y cuando salga con mouseLeave vuelva a su forma normal y lo oculte.

```
private void cancha1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        cancha1.SetBounds(15, 18, 339, 174);

        foreach (Control bt in this.cancha1.Controls)
        {
            bt.Visible = true;
        }
        foreach (Control bt in this.cp2.Controls)
        {
            bt.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void cancha1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        cancha1.SetBounds(16, 19, 328, 163);
        foreach (Control bt in this.cancha1.Controls)
        {
            bt.Visible = false;
        }
        foreach (Control bt in this.cp2.Controls)
        {
            bt.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

El error es que cuando entro al panel si me lo amplia y me lo muestra, pero cuando paso por encima de un botón (sin salir del panel) me lo vuelve poner pequeño. no se como hacer para que no me lo cambien. es como si cuando entra a componente notara que ha salido de su contenedor.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que esta pasando. cuando estas sobre el boton, estas saliendo del contenedor. Deberias tener una logica para que cuando entres al boton, no consideres que saliste del contenedor.

Comment: Si, la pregunta es como seria si tengo 12 botones ?

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias soluciones, te expondré una aquí. Lo que puedes hacer es comprobar en tu evento `MouseLeave` si el ratón está dentro de los límites del panel. Para ello, puedes hacer uso de la propiedad [`Bounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx) que tienen todo los controles, y comprobar si la posición del ratón está dentro de esos límites:

```
private void cancha1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!cancha1.Bounds.Contains(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
    {
        cancha1.SetBounds(16, 19, 328, 163);
        foreach (Control bt in this.cancha1.Controls)
        {
            bt.Visible = false;
        }
        foreach (Control bt in this.cp2.Controls)
        {
            bt.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Si te fijas, para obtener la posición del ratón se usa [`Cursor.Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx), que devuelve la posición del ratón en la pantalla. Como necesitamos la posición del ratón dentro del formulario, usamos el método [`PointToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx), que devuelve las coordenadas dentro del formulario.

Comment: huy se ve genial esta solucion, voy a intentar y te digo que sucede....

Comment: Pikoh master me persiste el problema, ya que cuando paso por encima de un boton se me restablece, y eso no es lo que quiero

Comment: @srJJ revisa bien el codigo. La solución que te he puesto esta probada y funciona correctamente. Si no es asi,edita tu pregunta y añade el codigo que tienes ahora mismo

Answer (score 0):

Mira @Pikoh este el código que puse después que tu me ayudaste, ya que tengo un error que si entró por la parte interna del panel a los botones entra con en una especie de ciclo infinito que empieza a entrar y salir, agrandando y empequeñeciendo el panel.

```
private void cancha1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("entro   ");

        cancha1.SetBounds(15, 18, 339, 174);

        foreach (Control bt in this.cancha1.Controls)
        {
            bt.Visible = true;
        }
        foreach (Control bt in this.cp1.Controls)
        {
            bt.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void cancha1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("salio   " + Cursor.Position);
        //Console.WriteLine("salio22   " + Bounds.Contains(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)));

        if (cancha1.Bounds.Contains(cancha1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
        {
            cancha1.SetBounds(16, 19, 328, 163);
            foreach (Control bt in cancha1.Controls)
            {
                bt.Visible = false;
            }
            foreach (Control bt in cp1.Controls)
            {
                bt.Visible = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

[image: como puedes ver en la imagen, en la parte de la consola tengo pruebas que me dice cuando entro y cuando sale del evento y pues cuando me paro encima de un botón queda entrando y saliendo sin control]

Comment: Varias cosas. Si la solucion de pikoh no sirvio no la marque como aceptada hasta q estes seguro q sirve (lo mas probable es q sirva, pero seamos coherentes si no soluciono el problema todavia no es una soluvion valida). Si tenes mas informacion no agregues una respuesta, edita tu pregunta. O comentale a pikoh q cosas no funcionan.

Comment: bueno señ@r....